# How to Determine a View Row's Content Type

Tags: views, 8

I'm putting together a view with multiple content types. In my my_theme.theme file I want to set the template suggestion based on the item's content type (e.g. Content-Type-A gets Template-A.twig and Content-Type-B gets Template-B.twig). Digging through the $variables[] array I can't find if or where there is an element that specifies the content type for the current view row.

Does any know how I may determine the content type of view row in the $variables[] array? If it's not in there what's the best way of adding it?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn’t it be easier to create a view mode or something for this purpose? I mean you’re already creating the twig files this route.

Comment: add a hidden field to the view with the node type then you can use {% if type== 'x'%} do stuff {%endif%}

Answer (score 0):

Create a new display mode and use this display mode on the view. then each of this display mode can be altered in admin or custom template can be made.

Comment: I'm not sure that I can rely on display modes. For my teasers used in the view, I'm pulling in statistics such as comment and view count. To do this (as far as I know) is to use "fields" instead of "content" and therefore display modes won't help. Thanks though :).